# global variable reassignment in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, hoisting

When I try to reassign a variable inside a function, I get error of `UnboundLocalError`. Following is a snippet of my problem.

```
global_variable = 'a'

def abc():
    print(global_variable)
    global_variable = 'b'

abc()
```

when I execute it then I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/arghyasaha/hobby_project/python_experiment/python_experiment/random_experiment/del_me.py", line 7, in <module>
    abc()
  File "/Users/arghyasaha/hobby_project/python_experiment/python_experiment/random_experiment/del_me.py", line 4, in abc
    print(global_variable)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'global_variable' referenced before assignment
```

To solve this issue we can use `global` keyword like this

```
global_variable = 'a'

def abc():
    global global_variable
    print(global_variable)
    global_variable = 'b'

abc()
```

I am looking for an explanation, to this behaviour, it seems somewhat similar to hoisting concept in javascript. I did find few resources, like [source1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules), [source2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37976957/block-scoping-in-python-is-it-similar-to-javascript-hoisting-when-inside-a-fun) but none of them explained well enough. Can someone give a proper explanation with what exactly happens under the hood in python?

Comment: Although people tend to call CPython an interpreted language, it is byte-code compiled: a function has its namespace initialised at compile time. Therefore, local variable `global_variable` is already in the namespace before you even call `print(global_variable)`, though it is unbound at that moment (that is no references are assigned to it), hence the error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python variable scope error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370357/python-variable-scope-error)

Answer (score 0):

This is because the Python compiler looks at all the l-values in a code block when determining which variables are local to that code block. Since in your code, `global_variable` is used as an l-value in the function block of `abc`, it is regarded as a variable local to the `abc` code block at compilation time, and as such, it is considered to be referenced before it is assigned a value within the `abc` when you try to `print(global_variable)` before you assign `global_variable` a value in the same block.

Answer (score 0):

A variable can't be both local and global inside of a function. So Python decides that we want a local variable due to the assignment to global_variable inside of abc(), so the first print statement before the definition of global_variable throws the error message above. Any variable which is changed or created inside of a function is local, if it hasn't been declared as a global variable. To tell Python, that we want to use the global variable, we have to explicitly state this by using the keyword "global"

you can refer *https://www.python-course.eu/python3_global_vs_local_variables.php* for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you run the code and it enters in the function this has a **scope**, where global_variable has not been defined yet.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you had written

```
def cba():
    global_variable = 'b'
    print(global_variable)

cba()
```

There wouldn't have been an exception. This is because, despite it's name, `global_variable` would be a local variable in the function's scope. Any variable you assign to in a function is local unless you explicitly tell it otherwise.

In a function, when you access a variable (use it's value somehow, like printing it in these examples), python will first look for the variable in the local scope, and then in the global scope.

```
def xyz():
    print(global_variable)
```

Would access the global variable, for example.

When python tries to compile your function, it sees that `global_variable` is assigned to, and therefore tries to treat it as local, but then it tries to access it before it's defined in that scope.

The `global` keyword tells python to treat that name as refering to something in the global scope for that function, therefore assignments change the global variable, and do not introduce a new variable in the local scope.